# Cannot use InfiniteScroll feature of ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, infinite-scroll, angular-ui-grid

Trying to use, without success, infinite scrolling feature of ui-grid.

Both 3.0.0-v16 and current unstable script version (released 2 days ago) were used. I'm following the example of http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/212_infinite_scroll .

When ui-grid calls `$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi(gridApi)` method, the injected `gridApi` object does not have a `infiniteScroll` member.

Indeed, the following line

```
gridApi.infiniteScroll.on.needLoadMoreData($scope, function () {...});
```

raises

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
at Object.$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi (http://...my-ctrl.js:144:35)
at Grid.renderingComplete (http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.js:4791:20)
```

Do you know what's wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not really an answer! I just use this for better code formating.

Did you write the html like this:

`<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-infinite-scroll></div>`

and did you inject the feature in your app?

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.infiniteScroll']);
```

Please remember that ui-grid is in development and those clever guys are working hard and have issues with keeping the documentation up to date.

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the `ui-grid-infinite-scroll` directive. As a personal thought, I consider 'by-the-example' ui-grid doc pedagogy especially poor.

Comment: Same problem for me also. I missed 'ui.grid.infiniteScroll' injection